# How to get country code from the store object

Tags: magento-1

This is my code:

```
 $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(1);
```

1- stands for Germany

I want to get the country code. In my case: `"DE"`. How do I get that  ?

Comment: you mean you want to get the code of the country from the language assigned to your store?

Comment: yep. is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$storeId = 1;  
$countryCode = substr(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId), 3);
```

Comment: it works, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but below should work, I have not tested but this should be work like below only

```
 echo $store->getCode();
```

Comment: This one returns me the store code and i want the country code. In my case is store_de_de  and the country code is DE

Comment: so on the basis of store you want to fetch country?? have you created mapping for this two ??

Comment: actually i want to get the country code for a customer using the store id in the adminpanel